# PostgreSQL non-standard selection (subgroupping)

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have some records:

```
+---+--------+---------------------------+
|   | Data   |            Time           |
+---+--------+---------------------------+
| 1 | 1      | 2013-04-22 16:18:07       |
| 2 | 1      | 2013-04-22 16:18:17       |
| 3 | 2      | 2013-04-22 16:18:27       |
| 4 | 2      | 2013-04-22 16:18:37       |
| 5 | 1      | 2013-04-22 16:18:47       |
| 6 | 1      | 2013-04-22 16:18:57       |
| 7 | 1      | 2013-04-22 16:19:07       |
| 8 | 3      | 2013-04-22 16:19:17       |
| 9 | 3      | 2013-04-22 16:19:27       |
| 10| 1      | 2013-04-22 16:19:37       |
| 11| 2      | 2013-04-22 16:19:47       |
| 12| 2      | 2013-04-22 16:19:57       |
| 13| 3      | 2013-04-22 16:20:07       |
| 14| 3      | 2013-04-22 16:20:17       |
+---+--------+---------------------------+
```

How i can get these records?:

```
+---+--------+---------------------------+
|   | Data   |            Time           |
+---+--------+---------------------------+
| 1 | 1      | 2013-04-22 16:18:07       |
| 3 | 2      | 2013-04-22 16:18:27       |
| 5 | 1      | 2013-04-22 16:18:47       |
| 8 | 3      | 2013-04-22 16:19:17       |
| 10| 1      | 2013-04-22 16:19:37       |
| 11| 2      | 2013-04-22 16:19:47       |
| 13| 3      | 2013-04-22 16:20:07       |
+---+--------+---------------------------+
```

i want to select the first entry for each subgroup, but if i use distinct - i have this array of records:

```
+---+--------+---------------------------+
|   | Data   |            Time           |
+---+--------+---------------------------+
| 1 | 1      | 2013-04-22 16:18:07       |
| 3 | 2      | 2013-04-22 16:18:27       |
| 8 | 3      | 2013-04-22 16:19:17       |
+---+--------+---------------------------+
```

Comment: What exactly is a "subgroup" in your example? I can find anything that those rows have in common.

Comment: What's the context? What are you trying to do?

Comment: "Subgroups" is items with ids: [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9], where neighboring rows contains same "Data" value.

Comment: Try using `lag` window function to acces previous row and discard current row if it has same `data`.

Comment: @madth3 It can be done with one small (but complex) query.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name As I see, the subgroups have same `data` and are close by `time`. But the questions looks like a homework.

Comment: it's don't homework. Игорь, подсказал бы лучше, в какую сторону копать, если не можешь помочь из-за того, что вопрос выглядит как "домашняя работа", несколько часов бьюсь над проблемой - решения не нашел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simpler and efficient version

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      id, 
      data, 
      time, 
      lag( id, 1 ) over( partition by data ORDER BY id ) as prev_id
    FROM t 
  ) t
WHERE 
  prev_id is null 
  OR id - prev_id > 1
ORDER BY
  id
```

Since you need to get the `first row` from every group, I use PostgreSQL window function [**lag()**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html), to produce a column named `prev_id` like the below one (the below table is only for those `records` where data is `1`, a similar table is created for other `data` values too)

```
+---+----------+
| id | prev_id | 
+---+----------+
| 1  | NULL    |  This row is valid as lag is NULL
| 2  | 1       | 
| 3  | 2       | 
| 5  | 3       |  This row is valid as diff is > 1 (between prevoius_id and current_id )
| 6  | 5       | 
| 7  | 6       |  
| 10 | 7       |  This row is valid as diff is > 1 (between prevoius_id and current_id )
```

Where either of the above 2 conditions, when `lag is NULL` OR `id-lag > 1` is `true` I consider this row to be `start row` for every `group`

[**SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/bdc43/27)

Comment: Thank you for answer, i ultimately came to the same decision)

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you need to define the groups that you are looking at.  The "data" values are repeated for different groups.

Here is a way to find each group.  Assign a sequential value to each of the rows, ordered by time.  Then, assign another sequential value for each data value, ordered by time.  The difference between these values is constant when the values are consecutive.

The following uses this idea on your data.  Once the groups are identified, this method uses `group by` to get the data:

```
select MIN(data) as data, MIN(time) as time
from (select t.*,
             (ROW_NUMBER() over (order by time) -
              ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by data order by time
             ) as thegroup
      from t
     ) t
group by thegroup
```

If you have more columns that you want to keep, then you can enumerate the rows in each group to grab the first one:

```
select data, time
from (select t.*, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by thegroup order by time) as seqnum
      from (select t.*,
                   (ROW_NUMBER() over (order by time) -
                    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by data order by time
                   ) as thegroup
            from t
           ) t
      group by thegroup
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

You can also do this using Postgres's `distinct on` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

use group by Data and Time instead of distinct

"group by Data" will group the rows by Data field but if you put the "and Time" it also group the group of Data's by Time